# What is a better design in Flink Sql

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-connect, flink-sql

I have a scenario at flink sql data processing which has many kafka message(json format).All of the messages content are similar but not the same. I created many flink tables one to one correspondence to the messages and I realise it is hard to maintance kafka topic.

```
event1:
{
    "id": "id_001",
    "type": "in",
    "create_time": 1635116133089, 
    "uid":"uid_001"
}
event2:
{
    "id":"id_002",
    "status":"login",
    "type":"in"
}
```

My flink sqls use watermark、 windows、 cep generally.

My pain point is I have variety of tables seems redundant. Is there a better table design in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thought would be to see if you can define a common schema for your events while using optional fields. You could then post all your events to one topic, since some fields can remain null.

Comment: Thanks. My idea is almost the same with your's . Use kafka-connector with confluent avro format, all events post to one topic